# Nested TouchableOpacity in a FlatList is not working properly

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I want to create custom Dropdown without using library so, I have created a FlatList of TouchableOpacity cards with a Kebab(ThreeDots) dropdown but the dropDown menu is not clicking properly.

Working: i have created a touchable flatlist for cards and nested another touchable for the kebab dropdown which get enable on the basis of id check and render on the basis of checks
DropDown menu is not clicking if it moves out from the card area View.

The code :

```
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Pressable,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Card = () => {
  const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState({
    visibility: false,
    id: '',
  });

  const dropDown = (item, index) => {
    setSideBar({
      visibility: !sideBar.visibility,
      id: item.id,
    });
  };

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          sideBar.id === item.id
            ? {
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
              }
            :  {
                // backgroundColor: '#123456',
              },
          {
            // flex: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
            height: 70,
            marginVertical: 8,
            marginHorizontal: 16,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderRadius: 10,
          },
        ]}
        onPress={(item, index) => {
          setSideBar({
            visibility: !sideBar.visibility,
            id: item.id,
          });
        }}>
        {/* TITLE */}
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginVertical: 5,
            marginHorizontal: 6,
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>

        {/*ADDRESS */}
        <View>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>1339 Arling Drive ODGEN, UT 84403</Text>
        </View>

        {/*ThreeDOTS */}
        <TouchableOpacity
          // style={{justifyContent:'flex-end',alignItems:'flex-end'}}
          onPress={() => dropDown(item, index)}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 30, height: 30}}
            source={require('../../assets/dots-vertical-512.webp')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
          {sideBar.visibility && sideBar.id === item.id ? (
            <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                width: 190,
                top: 50,
                right: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                backgroundColor:'red',
              }}>
              {/*DropDown 1 */}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => alert('D!!!')}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  height: 30,
                  width: '86%',
                  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  backgroundColor: '#abcdef',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    color: '#000000',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                  }}>
                  Send Text Message
                </Text>
                <Image
                  style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
                  source={require('../../assets/chat.png')}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {/*DropDown 1 */}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => alert('D!!!')}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  height: 30,
                  width: '86%',
                  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  backgroundColor: '#abcdef',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    color: '#000000',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                  }}>
                  Send Text Message
                </Text>
                <Image
                  style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
                  source={require('../../assets/chat.png')}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {/* DropDown 1 */}
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => alert('D!!!')}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  height: 30,
                  width: '86%',
                  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  backgroundColor: '#abcdef',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    color: '#000000',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                  }}>
                  Send Text Message
                </Text>
                <Image
                  style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
                  source={require('../../assets/chat.png')}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          ) : null}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Second Item',
      isMenuOpen: true,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '6',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '8',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
    {
      id: '9',
      title: 'Third Item',
      isMenuOpen: false,
    },
  ];

  return (
    // <SafeAreaView>
    <View
      style={[
        sideBar.visibility && sideBar.id
          ? {
              backgroundColor: '#808080',
            }
          : {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
      ]}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
    // </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Card;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // item: {
  //   flex: 1,
  //   borderWidth: 1,
  //   height: 70,
  //   marginVertical: 8,
  //   marginHorizontal: 16,
  //   flexDirection: 'row',
  //   justifyContent: 'space-between',
  //   alignItems: 'center',
  //   borderRadius: 10,
  // },
  title: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: any updates anyone